# Preventing Linux kernel from taking allocated memory from a process

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel

I want to allocate a large portion of memory using malloc() for an indefinite amount of time. I may touch the memory for a long time let say 1 minute. How do i prevent the kernel from taking that memory away from the process?

I can not re allocate that memory because it is being used by another device that is outside of the kernels control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Linux, you can allocate memory in user space, such as with `malloc` or a `mmap`, pass it down to the kernel, and then in the kernel, obtain references to the memory with `get_user_pages`. This will prevent the pages from going away, and also allow them to be accessed from any address space as `struct page *` references (and requiring `kmap` and `kunmap` if `CONFIG_HIGHMEM` is in effect).   These pages will not be contiguous physical memory, however, and they may not be in a suitable range for DMA.

Memory to be accessed by devices is usually allocated in the kernel (e.g. using `kmalloc` with `GFP_DMA`. For allocations larger than a page, `kmalloc` finds consecutive physical pages, too. Once obtained, `kmalloc`-ed memory can be mapped into user space with `remap_pfn_range`.